# Unsure how to fix pandas datetime concat issue

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

My data set has a 'year' column, a 'day' column, and a 'month' column. All of which are numbers. I have written the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
def read_and_clean(cur_file, airport_filter_string):

    airportsearch = pd.read_csv('/work/Data/AA.csv')

    airportsearch.dropna()
    [lambda x:
    (x['origin_airport'].isin(['SFO'])) &
    (x)['destination_airport'].isin (['SFO'])]
    
    airportsearch.columns = airportsearch.columns.str.lower()
```

#at this point things start going wrong. Below is the code that I have at the moment to create one DATE column from the three existing month, day, and year.

```
    airportsearch.rename(columns = {
     'a': 'year',
     'b': 'month',
     'c': 'day'}, 
     inplace = True)

     pd.concat(('year', 'month', 'day'), axis=1)
```

This the the error message I am getting though:

```py
File "/tmp/ipykernel_189/616128638.py", line 49, in read_and_clean
    pd.concat(('year', 'month', 'day'), axis=1)
  File "/shared-libs/python3.9/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 285, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "/shared-libs/python3.9/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 370, in __init__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

I have tried pd.datetime, but have gotten nothing but errors in every variation. I am unsure how to edit the error. Any insight would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The pandas docs are really good - I'd give them a read! As the error is trying to tell you, [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) doesn't do what you're trying to do at all. It concatenates multiple Series or DataFrames to form a larger Series or DataFrame, e.g. with more rows or columns - it does not concatenate the strings within a single series. Additionally, you need to pass it the actual objects to be concatenated. Your line `pd.concat(('year', 'month', 'day'), axis=1)` does not make any reference to `airportsearch`.

To concatenate the strings within these columns, simply add the columns:

```py
airportsearch["date"] = (
    airportsearch["year"]
    + airportsearch["month"]
    + airportsearch["day"]
)
```

This could be parsed using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) like so:

```py
airportsearch["date"] = pd.to_datetime(
    airportsearch["date"], format="%Y%m%d"
)
```